# Add JSON data to Android Studio map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have a JSON file which contains data about one city with name and numbers of all roads. I am developing a map for that city with search engine. How to add this file in Android Studio app and implement search between two locations?

```
 {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
         "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features": [
      {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties": {
            "Name": "yes",
            "description": "",
            "timestamp": null,
            "begin": null,
            "end": null,
            "altitudeMode": null,
            "tessellate": -1,
            "extrude": 0,
            "visibility": -1,
            "drawOrder": null,
            "icon": null,
            "description_1": null,
            "Number": "10",
            "RoadNameCo": "03_10234",
            "RoadNameAL": "Person Nmae"
         },
         "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               260.853835,
               426.601668,
               0
            ]
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You could put it in assests folder and using Gson, fetch this data.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to put your file in assets or in raw folder.

getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
                             "raw", getPackageName());

then using above lines you can get the data from raw folder.
after that you have you get all the location points from your JSON.

for that you can use this Async task to parse that JSON into Points

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String,
            String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if (lineOptions != null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Data Parser class

public class DataParser {

```
/**
 * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude
 */
public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jRoutes;
    JSONArray jLegs;
    JSONArray jSteps;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        /** Traversing all routes */
        for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
            jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<>();
            /** Traversing all legs */
            for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                /** Traversing all steps */
                for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude));
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude));
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }


    return routes;
}


/**
 * Method to decode polyline points
 * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}

Comment: any link for full tutorial do u have?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints but it will fetch direction from its api not from raw files. But you can use same procedure for your file data. For that your JSON should be of same format, this can help you further in future if you want to switch from raw file to google map api